# R: how to loop through multiple columns and store value in a vector for each category

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R.

I have a time series data set (60k rows) which also has a category built in. Take the example below: the table records each bus journey from 2001 to 2009. [enter image description here][1]

If a bus has multiple journeys, it then has multiple rows with the same bus number. The number of journeys per bus is random. The minimum number of journey is one.

I would like to reshape the data frame below into a table with n rows, where n is equal to the number of unique buses, and the columns shows the sequence of the stops each bus travels through time.

Therefore row one of the new table is
bus1 stop 1 stop20 stop 2 stop 21.

The second row of the table is
bus 2 stop 4 stop 23 stop 5 stop 25 stop 6 stop 25 stop 7 stop 26 stop 8 stop 27.

Since these buses do not have the same number of journeys, the converted table/list do not have the same number of columns.

I don't know what is the best way to reshape the dataset. Should I use loop?

Many thanks

Take the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  transport = c("bus1", "bus1", "bus2", "bus2", "bus2",  
            "bus2", "bus2", "bus2", "bus3", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4",  
            "bus4", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4"),
  travel_time = c(2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2003,
                  2004, 2005, 2006, 2001, 2001,2002,2003, 
                 2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
  from = paste("stop",seq(1,18)),
  to = paste("stop",seq(20,37))
)
```

Comment: Your code does not do anything. You are missing a `}` and when that is added, we get "Error in filter(df, state == sta) : object 'state' not found". If your data is as regular as your example (same number of categories repeated the same number of times in each state, `state1 <- rep(1:3, 3)` should work.

Comment: by_state <- list()

for (sta in unique(df$state)) {
    by_state[[sta]] <- filter(df, state == sta)
}

Comment: Same error message I quoted above. Are you using the `filter()` function in the base R `stats` package or have you loaded packages not shown in your code?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want form you want the output to be in - so this might not give you exactly what you want.
(That's common with people new to R. As with any programming language, there's lots of specialist terminology.) And 'filter' doesn't do what you seem to think it does, unless you're using a particular library you haven't mentioned.

First, splitting a table by a particular column can be done with split. The following gives you a list of two dataframes,
one for state == "state1", the other for state == "state2".

```
by_state <- split(df,df$state)
```

You was looping over both state and category - looping over category doesn't do anything. You just end up doing the selection three times, overwriting the result in by_state[[sta]] with the same value on the second and third time round.

I gather you want to re-arrange the three columns y2001, y2002, y2003 into a single column or vector, and drop the category column. I'm not quite sure what you want - you say 'table' but that's a specific type of object in R output by the table() function, and probably not what you're after. Going by your desired output, I'm going to guess by 'table' you mean a vector.

Now, you want to 'zip' together several vectors, to take c(1,1,1,...), c(2,2,2,...), c(3,3,3,...) and produce c(1,2,3,1,2,3,...).
There's a useful trick for doing this using 'rbind'. Here's how to use it on three lists of 1's, 2's, and 3's.

```
c(rbind(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5)))
```

This relies on the way R stores arrays, which is to put all the elements in a single vector in a column-first order, and then stick on an attribute to tell R it's actually a p-by-q array. 'rbind' sticks the vectors together into an 2-by-n array, and then 'c' drops the attribute and turns it into a vector, now in the right order.

We want to apply this process to each element of the by-state list. If you have come from another programming language you are likely to automatically think of using a loop. That's often inefficient in R (because it usually involves lots of redundant memory management) and it's a good idea to get into the habit of using functional programming instead.

We want to apply a function to every element of a list, returning a list of results. For that, we want the 'lapply' function.

```
lapply(split(df,df$state), function(d){c(rbind(d$y2001,d$y2002,d$y2003))})
```

That returns two vectors.

But it's possible you actually did want something like a dataframe, and it's a useful thing to know about. There's a library for rearranging data in a variety of ways that has become its own programming paradigm. It's called the '[tidyverse](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html)', because it keeps your data tidy!

This isn't the place to go into how to use it properly, but your particular example can be done this way:

```
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(pivot_longer(df,cols=c("y2001","y2002","y2003"),names_to="year",values_to="value"))
```

That returns a data structure called a 'tibble', which is like a cut-down dataframe. (The idea is that it's less likely to try to guess what you really wanted and do something unhelpful.) If you specifically wanted a dataframe anyway, you can still use the as.data.frame() function to convert.

Comment: Hi Nullius in Verba, many thanks for your help. I apologise for the poor description of my question. I have redrafted it. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better approaches, as I am an R beginner myself, but I would do it as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
        transport = c("bus1", "bus1", "bus2", "bus2", "bus2",  
                "bus2", "bus2", "bus2", "bus3", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4",  
                "bus4", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4", "bus4"),
        travel_time = c(2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2003,
                2004, 2005, 2006, 2001, 2001,2002,2003, 
                2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009),
        from = paste("stop",seq(1,18)),
        to = paste("stop",seq(20,37))
)


library(tidyr)
df_bus <- df %>%
        #unpivot from/to columns into variable and value columns 
        pivot_longer(cols = c(from, to)) %>%
        #combine year information with from/to, so this information is not lost
        transform(year_fromto=paste0(travel_time, "_", name)) %>%
        #pivot the from/to columns per bus id 
        pivot_wider(id_cols= transport, names_from = year_fromto, values_from = value)

print(df_bus)
```

Sample output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 19
  transport `2001_from` `2001_to` `2002_from` `2002_to` `2003_from` `2003_to`
  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     <chr>       <chr>    
1 bus1      stop 1      stop 20   stop 2      stop 21   <NA>        <NA>     
2 bus2      stop 3      stop 22   stop 4      stop 23   stop 5      stop 24  
3 bus3      stop 9      stop 28   <NA>        <NA>      <NA>        <NA>     
4 bus4      stop 10     stop 29   stop 11     stop 30   stop 12     stop 31  
# … with 12 more variables: `2004_from` <chr>, `2004_to` <chr>,
#   `2005_from` <chr>, `2005_to` <chr>, `2006_from` <chr>, `2006_to` <chr>,
#   `2007_from` <chr>, `2007_to` <chr>, `2008_from` <chr>, `2008_to` <chr>,
#   `2009_from` <chr>, `2009_to` <chr>
```